# Copy a HTML snippet of the page to a clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, clipboard

I am developing web development tools and I'd like to copy of a part of current web page's HTML code to the clipboard using Javascript.

This probably would involve

- Getting the piece of HTML in the question using DOM innerHTML
- Copying this text to clipboard using Javascript

Is anyone aware of any gotchas here? E.g. related to clipboard handling - when one is not using documentEditable mode do I need to create a hidden  where to put the HTML payload for copying?

Also if possible I'd like to make the interaction with WYSIWYG components, like TinyMCE, work so that when one pastes the HTML in the visual edit mode it comes through as formatted HTML instead of plain text.

It is enough if solution works in Chrome and Firefox. Internet Explorer does not need to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has no way of adding things to the clipboard. Well at least not any that works cross browser.

There is however a flash solution which works well. http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Comment: Google Docs is doing custom Copy action in right click menu. I'd be satisfied with FF + Chrome solution and forget IE. It's for web developers so I don't need to cater IE users.

Comment: +1 javascript has indeed no way of adding things to the clipboard

Comment: actually you can: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3458851

Comment: ZeroClipboard is no longer available on code.google.com. Find it now here: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

Answer (score 1):

We developed a small Firefox-AddOn to remove special characters (hyphens) when copy/pasting content from the editor. This has been necessary because there is no javascript way to fill anyting into the clipboard. I guess it should be possible to write an extension for Chrome too (googel is your friend here). This seems to be the only way to get what you want from my point of view.

**Example:**
Here is the necessary code snippet for a FireFox-Addon to remove special characters onCopy

```
// get Clipboard Object
var clip  = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);

// get Transferable Object
    var tr_unicode = new Transferable(); 
var tr_html    = new Transferable();

// read "text/unicode flavors" (the clipboard has several "flavours" (html, plain text, ...))
    tr_unicode.addDataFlavor("text/unicode");
tr_html.addDataFlavor("text/html");
    clip.getData(tr_unicode, clip.kGlobalClipboard); // Systemclipboard
    clip.getData(tr_html, clip.kGlobalClipboard); // Systemclipboard

// generate objects to write the contents into (used for the clipboard)         
    var unicode = { }, ulen = { }, html = { }, hlen = { };

tr_html.getTransferData("text/html", html, hlen);
tr_unicode.getTransferData("text/unicode", unicode, ulen);

var unicode_obj = unicode.value.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
var html_obj    = html.value.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);

// we remove Softhyphen and another control character here
var re = new RegExp('[\u200b' + String.fromCharCode(173)+ ']','g');

if (unicode_obj && html_obj)
{
    var unicode_str = unicode_obj.data.replace(re, '');
    var html_str    = html_obj.data.replace(re, '');

    // Neue Stringkomponenten für unicode und HTML-Content anlegen      
    var unicode_in = new StringComponent();
    unicode_in.data = unicode_str;

    var html_in = new StringComponent();
    html_in.data = html_str;

    // generate new transferable to write the data back to the clipboard
    // fill html + unicode flavors
    var tr_in = new Transferable();
    tr_in.setTransferData("text/html", html_in, html_in.data.length * 2);
    tr_in.setTransferData("text/unicode", unicode_in, unicode_in.data.length * 2);

    // copy content from transferable back to clipboard     
    clip.setData(tr_in, null, clip.kGlobalClipboard);
}
```